# rtkit gives ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, rest, rt

I have a python script using python-rtkit to try and create tickets in Request Tracker (RT) and I can get it to work with the Queue, Subject, and Status fields.  But I tried to add the 'Device or Area' field into my payload and it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resttest.py", line 23, in <module>
    response = resource.post(path='ticket/new', payload=content)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\rtkit\resource.py", line 29, in post
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\rtkit\resource.py", line 49, in request
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\rtkit\resource.py", line 104, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\rtkit\parser.py", line 49, in parse
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\rtkit\parser.py", line 79, in decode_comment
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Here's my code

```
from rtkit.resource import RTResource
from rtkit.authenticators import BasicAuthenticator, CookieAuthenticator
from rtkit.errors import RTResourceError

from rtkit import set_logging
import logging
set_logging('debug')
logger = logging.getLogger('rtkit')

resource = RTResource(rt_url, rt_user, rt_pass, CookieAuthenticator)

#create a ticket
content = {
    'content': {
        'Queue': 'General - unassigned',
        'Subject' : 'Test Ticket Python 2',
        'Status' : 'open',
        'Device or Area' : 'Backups',
        }
    }
try:
    print content
    response = resource.post(path='ticket/new', payload=content,)
    logger.info(response.parsed)
except RTResourceError as e:
    logger.error(e.response.status_int)
    logger.error(e.response.status)
    logger.error(e.response.parsed)
```

Does anyone know what this error means and what's causing it (so that I can fix it)?

EDIT: I believe that it's worth noting that if I just remove the 'Device or Area' entry for the new ticket that it works fine.  It's the adding of that field (or just about any other field for that matter) that breaks the code.

EDIT: @sihrc
Here's the output from running without the nested dict structure

```
{'Queue': 'General - unassigned', 'Status': 'open', 'Device or Area': 'Backups',
 'Subject': 'Test Ticket Python 2'}
[DEBUG] POST ticket/new
[DEBUG] {'Content-Length': '601', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary
=xXXxXXyYYzzz', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
[DEBUG] '--xXXxXXyYYzzz\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Queue"\r\nConte
nt-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 24\r\n\r\nGeneral%20-%20un
assigned\r\n--xXXxXXyYYzzz\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Status"\r\nC
ontent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 4\r\n\r\nopen\r\n--xXX
xXXyYYzzz\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Device%20or%20Area"\r\nConten
t-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 7\r\n\r\nBackups\r\n--xXXxX
XyYYzzz\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Subject"\r\nContent-Type: text/
plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 26\r\n\r\nTest%20Ticket%20Python%202\r\n
--xXXxXXyYYzzz--\r\n'
[INFO] POST
[INFO] https://rt.redactedurl.com/REST/1.0/ticket/new
[DEBUG] HTTP_STATUS: 200 OK
[DEBUG] 'RT/3.6.6 200 Ok\n\n# Required: id, Queue\n\nid: ticket/new\nQueue: \nRe
questor: jgreen\nSubject: \nCc:\nAdminCc:\nOwner: \nStatus: new\nPriority: \nIni
tialPriority: \nFinalPriority: \nTimeEstimated: 0\nStarts: 2013-07-29 16:19:19\n
Due: 2013-07-29 16:19:19\nText: \n\n'
[DEBUG] RESOURCE_STATUS: 200 Ok
[INFO] [[('id', 'ticket/new'), ('Queue', ''), ('Requestor', 'jgreen'), ('Subject
', ''), ('Cc', ''), ('AdminCc', ''), ('Owner', ''), ('Status', 'new'), ('Priorit
y', ''), ('InitialPriority', ''), ('FinalPriority', ''), ('TimeEstimated', '0'),
 ('Starts', '2013-07-29 16:19:19'), ('Due', '2013-07-29 16:19:19'), ('Text', '')
]]
[INFO] [[('id', 'ticket/new'), ('Queue', ''), ('Requestor', 'jgreen'), ('Subject
', ''), ('Cc', ''), ('AdminCc', ''), ('Owner', ''), ('Status', 'new'), ('Priorit
y', ''), ('InitialPriority', ''), ('FinalPriority', ''), ('TimeEstimated', '0'),
 ('Starts', '2013-07-29 16:19:19'), ('Due', '2013-07-29 16:19:19'), ('Text', '')
]]
```

After this no new ticket is created.

Comment: straight up do content = {'Queue....} without additional content. I'm not sure myself, but that's how I've seen some been done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Device or Area' looks to be a custom field, so you'll want to add a 'CF-' to the front of it to match what the RT REST interface expects for custom fields. You can see the underlying REST syntax [on the community wiki here](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST#Ticket_Create).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the error means exactly but I was able to fix it by changing the key for Device or Area because apparently what it's marked as in the page and what it's stored as in the database are different.